# ARRW - Another RewriteRule wondering

Tags: model-view-controller, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, symfony

I'm sorry for this as there has been lots instances of such question, but I can't get through.

### Request

In the Symfony2 project, I want to access pages without having the php controller in the URL, e.g :

```
# This is the present use :
GET /af/index.php/myURI HTTP/1.1
OK
```

~

```
# And this is the wanted use :
GET /af/monURI HTTP/1.1
```

But I get a 404 error, either with the default .htaccess or an own version.

### .htaccess

Default .htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I modified this as follows :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
#    RewriteBase /af
#    Options +FollowSymLinks
# Isn't the request for a regular file ?
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

### Directory Structure

Here is my directory structure :

```
/var/www/af
         ├── app
         ├── bin
         ├── src
         ├── vendor
         └── web
             ├── app_dev.php
             ├── apple-touch-icon.png
             ├── bundles
             ├── config.php
             ├── favicon.ico
             ├── .htaccess
             ├── index.php
             └── robots.txt
```

I have **dynamically linked the web/ directory to /var/www/af**

Edit - I have found **[this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)** :

> When using the rewrite engine in .htaccess files the per-directory
>   prefix (which always is the same for a specific directory) is
>   automatically removed for the RewriteRule pattern matching and
>   automatically added after any relative (not starting with a slash or
>   protocol name) substitution encounters the end of a rule set. See the
>   RewriteBase directive for more information regarding what prefix will
>   be added back to relative substitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't change .htaccess file rules.

If you have access to webserver config files (i.e. local dev or virtual machine), then you need to add VirtualHost rule into `httpd.conf`.
Something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/af/web"
    ServerName af
    <directory "/var/www/af/web">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If you don't have access to webserver config files (i.e. shared hosting), then you need to have `web` folder linked as the public access folder (sometimes named `public_html`)

Comment: I cannot do this. This is a git-controlled project and I don't want to configure a virtualhost on each deployment. As a matter of fact this kind of redirection is made into most CMSes (Joomla, Drupal, Wordpress, etc.) and we don't have to add a new virtualhost.

Comment: Okay, your answer was inside : I had to add "AllowOverride all" to the generic public document root. Thanks :-)

Comment: Haha, glad I could help.. I guess.. :-D

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, thanks to [*Mac*](http://www.developpez.net/forums/d1140601/webmasters-developpement-web/serveurs-apache-iis/apache/symfony2-404-on-retire-index-php-lurl/) : My document root didn't allow overrites for htaccess.